# .htaccess settings to get value after "/" as an GET variable

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

example consider http://example.com/abcdef

I want this to be changed to http://example.com/?id=abcdef

How can this be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /uppit/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: not working it displays a blank page probably I thought it should be `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]` but it gives an 404 error.

Comment: What is location of this .htaccess and what URL did you use to test?

Comment: both are in an directory named uppit

Comment: You're welcome. http://www.askapache.com is pretty good resource and of course our SO collection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.htaccess

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On # Turn on the rewriting engine 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```